# CSS Media Queries Unexpected behavior

Tags: css, media-queries

I’m getting some odd results with my tests. I’m using a dual monitor setup and while testing the media queries on the “main” monitor,everything works just fine width scaling the browser window etc. But when I move the browser to the secondary monitor, I’m getting orientation landscape back and the design switches to the “tablet mode”.

Windows 7 64

**Chrome**:

Gets orientation on secondary monitor

**FF5**:

Gets orientation on secondary monitor

**Opera 11.5**:

Gets orientation on All monitors

**IE9**:

Works as expected

Sample Code:

```
/* CSS Document */
* { margin:0px; padding:0px; }

#pc { background:red; }

@media (max-width:1280px) {
    #pc { background:white; }
    #pc2 { background:red; }
}

@media (max-device-width:1280px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    #pc { background:white; }
    #tablet_andr_ls { background:red; }
}

@media (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    #pc { background:white; }
    #tablet_ipad_ls { background:red; }
}

@media (max-device-width:800px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    #pc { background:white; }
    #tablet_andr_pt { background:red; }
}

@media (max-device-width:768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    #pc { background:white; }
    #tablet_ipad_pt { background:red; }
}
```

HTML Sample:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="pc"><p>PC Huge</p></div>

    <div id="pc2"><p>PC Small</p></div>

    <div id="tablet_andr_ls"><p>Android Tablet: Orientation Landscape</p></div>

    <div id="tablet_ipad_ls"><p>iPad Tablet: Orientation Landscape</p></div>

    <div id="tablet_andr_pt"><p>Android Tablet: Orientation Portrait</p></div>

    <div id="tablet_ipad_pt"><p>iPad Tablet: Orientation Portrait</p></div>

    <div id="smartphone"><p>Smart phone</p></div>

</div>
```

Comment: How many of your visitors do you expect to have a dual monitor setup? Please spend your time on fun things instead of trying to find edge case problems.

Comment: Crazy question: Do you have your screens setup like one big monitor with one resolution or two monitors with their own resolutions. I've seen both of those setups.

Comment: 2 Monitors with extended desktop. The main is a 27" 2560x1440 and secondary is a smaller 19" 1280x1024. I guess it is one large desktop.

Comment: @Gerben Well I'm not trying to find problems. As I've posted there is a problem with the Opera. It doesn't work at all. Another "weird" thing is on the android phone the browser reports always 800px of width, either on portrait or landscape mode. Same goes for my android tablet, it reports always 1088px width.

Comment: device-width always returns the width of the screen regardless of orientation (as the spec requires). To get the width of the screen in the current orientation you have to use width (max-width in you case). You also need a <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> off course.

Comment: Found how to suppress the permanent width on the android devices. <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `max-width` and `min-width` instead of `device-max-width`, the min/max-width follows window size, the device-min/max-width will follow device size.